# Counting Words In A Sentence

Tags: java, string, count, words

I am trying to write a program to calculate the number of words in a sentence. I am using the `split` method with the String argument `" "`. When I enter a string say `Hello World`, I get an output : `No. of words Are 1` while it should be `2`. Did I miss something ? Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Duplicate {

String Sentence;
String Store[];

public String getString(){

    System.out.println("Enter A String");
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    Sentence = S.nextLine();
    return Sentence;
}

public void count(){

    Store = Sentence.split("  ");
    System.out.println("No. Of words are " +Store.length);
    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Duplicate D = new Duplicate();
    D.getString();
    D.count();

}
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter A String
Hello World
No. Of words are 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line when you should split by *one* **space**:

***`Store = Sentence.split("  ");`***

You are splitting by *two* **spaces**.

look at this to find the duplicates:

```
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));

        Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(list);
        for (String word : uniqueWords) {
            System.out.println(word + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, word));
        }
```

Comment: Yes! Right. I didn't even get to know when I tapped the `spacebar` twice in between the `""` :P

Comment: Hahaha, yeah it happens

Comment: Need another help. You there ?

Comment: @LancePreston yep shure . .  .

Comment: Can you come to chat ?

Comment: yeah sure just publish here the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57236/discussion-between-lance-preston-and-gingerhead).